# How to design a non-flat UI in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

Is there any possibility to create non flat designs in *C#*? *XAML* doesn't seem to have a feature to implement inner shadows for `buttons`, `dropdowns`  and other control forms without any borders?

- http://imagr.eu/up/RSsvY_presentation_2.jpg
- http://imagr.eu/up/3uaE1_presentation_3.jpg

Comment: Your question is very vague. In any case, XAML does support template modification, which can be used to customize any control in the framework.

Comment: Do you have any tutorials about that? Me and a friend of mine are on it for 2 days now.

Comment: What are you programming for? normal c# application?

Comment: Yes, a normal C# application.

Edit: Here are some screens of the application:
http://imagr.eu/up/avV5L_presentation_1.jpg
http://imagr.eu/up/RSsvY_presentation_2.jpg
http://imagr.eu/up/3uaE1_presentation_3.jpg
http://imagr.eu/up/kDNek_presentation_4.jpg

Comment: @Lix0r Do you have Blend? If so, you can use it to modify your controls. There are a lot of examples out there showing you how to do it.

Comment: We are already using blend and couldn't find any tutorials showing us ways to create the UI like I designed it.

Comment: Everything is design-able once you become familiar with the style/control template structures. There's loads of tutorials out there for it, but much of the custom stuff will require your own creativity and learning how things work. [Example](http://professionalsweb.net/GleemTheme/GleemTheme-v.05/PrecompiledWeb/TwoToneControlTheme-CWSite/) (old silverlight example, but wpf/wp/winrt and others all work similiar and are just as much, if not more customizable)

Answer (score 3):

To create non-flat controls, fill the backgrounds with linear and radial gradient brushes.

If you don't know how to create the brushes in XAML you can use Blend to design the brushes.

For borderless windows set the WindowStyle of the window to None.

Here is an example:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="Click Me"
        Foreground="White">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FF4D4C4C" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FF1D1D1D" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <ContentPresenter Margin="10"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Yeah that works for buttons. Atleast not properly but it's okay. But other controls like the dropdowns are still in default style and not designable on this way.

Comment: @Lix0r -  It does work for all controls. Just look up the ControlTemplate properties of the controls to see how they work. All parts of all controls can be replaced.